# Keep light fixed when using THREE.ShaderTerrain in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a sphere and light source (basically sun and earth). On the sphere, I'm using a greyscale heightmap for terrain texture so I am using three.js's ShaderTerrain.js. I'm also using a directional light source. My code:

```
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
lightCamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
lightControls = new THREE.TrackballControls(lightCamera, renderer.domElement);

light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
light.position.set(0,0,20);
lightCamera.position.z = 225;
lightCamera.add(light);
camera.add(lightCamera);
scene.add(camera);

var terrainShader = THREE.ShaderTerrain[ "terrain" ];
uniformsTerrain = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(terrainShader.uniforms);

// displacement is heightmap (greyscale image)
uniformsTerrain[ "tDisplacement" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('heightmap.jpg');
uniformsTerrain[ "uDisplacementScale" ].value = 15;

// diffuse is texture overlay
uniformsTerrain[ "tDiffuse1" ].value = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('earth.jpg');
uniformsTerrain[ "enableDiffuse1" ].value = true;

var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms:       uniformsTerrain,
    vertexShader:   terrainShader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: terrainShader.fragmentShader,
    lights:         true,
    fog:            false
});

var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100,100,100);
geometry.computeTangents();

scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material));
```

With this code, the sphere is created just fine with the raised texture and everything.

The problem is that when I rotate the sphere, the light source doesn't appear to stay fixed. It rotates with the sphere and you end up with dark spots (rather than the light always coming from the front and keeping what the users sees illuminated).

If I create a simple sphere instead, like so:

```
geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(100,100,100);
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x00ee00, wireframe: true, transparent: true, needsUpdate: true});
sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);
```

Everything works perfectly. The light source stays fixed while the sphere/camera rotates.

I've also tried code that simply rotates the (first) sphere (the one using the `ShaderMaterial`) and not the camera (attaching a function to the `mousemove` event and simply doing a `sphere.rotation.x/y` with the mouse position). This doesn't work either; When the sphere rotates, there are still shadows that appear to the user.

Not sure what I'm missing here.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5sS5/1/. Left click/drag to spin everything (camera + light), right click/drag to spin only the light. To see it working, keep `basicSphere()` uncommented. To see it not working, comment `basicSphere()` and uncomment `terrainSphere()`.

Comment: 1. Why do you have two cameras, with one camera a child of the other? 2. Why are you setting `needsUpdate: true` in your material constructor? 3. It does not make much sense to have a `DirectionalLight` as a child of an object that can move and rotate. Use the omnidirectional `PointLight` instead.

Comment: Apparently I left that line of code out of my example (which I've edited back in). I'm also using controls to move the light camera around. When I use the left mouse button, it rotates everything. When I use the right mouse button, it rotates only the light camera.

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment anymore, but I did try what you suggested. I used a `PointLight` and added it to the `camera` (no 2-camera-method). This works just fine when using the sphere with `MeshLambertMaterial` but once I have a sphere with `ShaderMaterial`, the light source doesn't appear to stay fixed.

Comment: Sorry, I really have no idea what you are doing. Why do you have two cameras, with one camera a child of the other? Do you understand the mathematics behind the `TerrainShader`?

Comment: Here's a pretty basic example of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5sS5/. Left click/drag and the entire camera (sphere + light) rotates. Right click/drag, and only the light camera moves. Setting it up with 2 cameras, one being the child of the other, was the only way I was able to get this to work (though I don't claim it to be the only or best way of doing this). And no, I don't understand the math behind the `TerrainShader`.

Comment: Sorry, use this jsfiddle instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5sS5/1/. This has the 2nd sphere where the lighting isn't as I expect. Simply comment out `basicSphere()` and uncomment `terrainSphere` to see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, what you are doing is so out-of-the-norm, I can't help you. See if you can find another, more conventional, approach. I will be glad to answer three.js questions, but I can't help you debug your code.

Comment: Fair enough. But if it's the controls part that's out of the normal, then I can give you an example using "normal" methods: http://jsfiddle.net/Z5sS5/3/. No two control scheme, no multiple cameras. The light is added to the camera, from your suggestion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456912/point-spotlight-in-same-direction-as-camera-three-js-flashlight) (among others). Seems pretty basic, but the `ShaderMaterial` sphere still handles the light differently that the `MeshLambertMaterial` sphere (which I concede could stem from my lack of understanding of the math behind the former).

Comment: I bet there is an implicit assumption in the `TerrainShader` that the geometry is flat to begin with. http://jsfiddle.net/Z5sS5/4/ -- just a guess, though.