# Spotlight in corners Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to use PointerLockControls and spotlight as a flashlight attached and targeted to the camera, but I'm getting "unwanted results" or I just have not found a "working examle" where the spotlight directs its beam to the corner not on the sides when facing a corner.

Can it be achieved with one spotlight with a straight direction or do I have to manipulate two different lights from the sides to get the light in the center of the corners or something like that?

[Illustrative image of current behaviour and wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfkZY.png)

Using flashlight examples described in [Point SpotLight in same direction as camera three.js (Flashlight)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456912/point-spotlight-in-same-direction-as-camera-three-js-flashlight)

```
function user_box() {
    var group = new THREE.Group();
    group.position.y = 0.001 - 10;
    controls.getObject().add( group );

    bigball = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.3, 16, 16 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0040 } ) );
    group.add(bigball);
    bigball.position.set(0, 10, -5);

    flashlight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff,4,40);
    group.add(flashlight);
    flashlight.position.set(0,10,0);
    flashlight.target = bigball;
}
```

Added demo as suggested http://codepen.io/BringerOfTheDawn/pen/LxMbex

Comment: It would be great to see your code to know how you create an instance of `THREE.SpotLight()` and how you set its properties (jsfiddle, for example). Also you can have a look at [THREE.SpotLight() documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Lights/SpotLight)

Comment: @BringerOfTheDawn `flashlight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1, 1000,  Math.PI / 8, 1 );` Experiment until you understand what all of the parameters are for -- and that goes for your materials, too.

Comment: @WestLangley I knew it had to be something simple. I played around with the angle at the beginning but when I stumbled upon my corners, I just expected to see something similar as it was casted on walls. Could you post your comment as an answer, as a beginner I found other flashlight examples really disappointing without these parameters =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your spotlight has a wide angle and a short range. Decrease the angle and increase the range. Also experiment with the other parameters so you understand their implications.

```
flashlight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1, 1000, Math.PI / 8, 1 )
```

three.js r.84